# Python paramiko cannot read output of ./a.out

Tags: python

I wrote a script based on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680929/2431645).

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('1.1.1.1',username='admin',password='admin')
w,r,e = ssh.exec_command('ls ./home/')

print(''.join(r.readlines()))

ssh.close()
```

If it executes `exec_command('ls ./home/')`, it will return all files in that folder.

```
a.out
hello.cl
hello.cpp
```

If it executes `exec_command('./home/a.out')`, it returns nothing. I expect a string of `'hello world'` or other error messages. **[Solved, see the first answer]**

If I type `./home/a.out` in the terminal of the server, it outputs `Failed to load kernel.`. Yes, this is an OpenCL error message. Why this error message is not caught by paramiko? **[Unsolved]**

Answer (score 0):

While I am writing this question, I suddenly realized that I should try

`exec_command('cd home; ./a.out')`

It works! Such easy!