# send linux command to other computers via socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to "control" another linux computer by sending commands via its sockets, for example, send a command `ls` to 123.222.12.1:5050. [*This is an example of what I'm interested in implementing*](http://www.oir.caltech.edu:8080/DETECT/P200_Echelle/echelle_soft_user_manual/DBSP_Scripting.html)

If we do not use the special code (`sendsockcmd`) as shown in the above weblink, are there other ways to do this in python?

Comment: Does it have to be in python? Why not just use SSH for example?

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) module, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko).