# nested terminal sessions using paramiko ssh client

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko

How to properly handle situation when user wants to start over ssh new terminal session - executing `exec_command('bash')`. Currently while doing it this way, function hangs out.

Comment: Are you looking for an interactive terminal session over Paramiko?

Comment: basically yes, but i would like handle it in a smart way. I mean whenever user prompts non-interactive command, execute it, return result and close the session, otherwise follow user interaction. And of course handle special case which seems to be execution of "bash" command

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko