# waiting forever with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running interactive commands in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko)

I am very new to Python. I am trying to run a batch file on a remote computer with paramiko:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("host", username="uname", password="pwd", allow_agent = False)
i, o, e = ssh.exec_command("c://test.bat")
print o.read()
```

The problem is that the remote batch file at some point is waiting for input (pause) so I am stuck after the read command and nothing prints out.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If paramiko is not a strict requirement, you could consider [fabric](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/) with [fexpect](http://ilogue.com/jasper/blog/fexpect--dealing-with-prompts-in-fabric-with-pexpect/):

```
from fexpect import expect, expecting, run 

prompts = []
prompts += expect('What is your name?','John')

with expecting(prompts):
    run('c://test.bat')
```