# Flask app running on webserver to call remote server python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a flask app running on my webserver to make calls to different remote servers based on hostname POST'ed from user selection. The webserver flask app makes SSH calls (using `paramiko`) to user desired hostnames to run a python script.

Currently, I have to manually create a python script for each function I want to call in the backend or else I would run into import errors (since my webserver flask does not have the same python environment as the remote server).

For example, on my backend remote server if I want to call a function from my backend Python module I have to create something like this:

myScript.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from myPackage import myModule
myModule.myFunction()
```

And call it from the webserver flask app like this:

```
client.exec_command('(cd /myDir; ./myScript.py:)')
```

My question is, is there a way to stimulate the backend python environment and make calls directly to the python modules, or even some how be able to import the modules from the backend, so I don't have to create a separate script for each function I want to call?

Comment: How about retrieving the file with the function you'd like to call directly (at runtime), saving it temporarily and then importing the temporary file regularly?

Comment: @Jonas My remote server is installed via python package, I won't be able to just retrieve a single file, because some of the files' function calls are dependent on other modules. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two python interpreter options that may interest you:

1. If [you run it as](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) `python -c "print('foobar')"` you can pass your script as text and don't create any files on your remotes.
2. If you run it on remote as `python -` it will start in an interactive mode and listed your commands from a stdin. I've never done it with paramiko, but [as I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko), paramiko supports running commands in the interactive mode.

P.S. Still not sure if I've understood your question correctly, hope this helps.