# Get past user/pass prompt in a shell script using PySFTP

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

I am connecting to a server using pysftp. Sending commands using the .execute functionality works just fine. Example of what works:

```
SftpConn.execute('cd ' + RemotePath + ';gzgrep -l ' + eventid + ' ' + ModuleId + '*')
```

But now I have a shell script I want to execute, which will prompt me for a username and a password. I can't seem to pass that information.

```
    conn = pysftp.Connection(host=server, username=user, password=pw, cnopts=cnopts)
    conn.put(localpath, remotepath) 
    print('0')
    conn.execute('sh /home/tools/testtool')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('1')
    conn.execute(user2)
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('2')
    conn.execute(pw2)
```

This prints 0 and then it's stuck. I think it's because the conn.execute('sh /home/tools/testtool') command is waiting for a return value that's never going to come. Any ideas how to get this going? Can I make it time out, or better yet, send a command without wanting a return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for Paramiko rather than pysftp, I think this thread holds the answer.

[Running interactive commands in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373639/running-interactive-commands-in-paramiko)